# Proof of Expected value by Abel's Summation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-functions, summation-by-parts

> Using Abel's summation lemma, prove that: 
>   $$
> \mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) \ dx,
> $$
>   where $F(x)$ is the CDF of a random variable $X$

I do know how to prove this equation by another method. But using Abel's summation is definitely out of my zone. Please give me some advices.